# How to add element in the end of array Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have one array in Angular JS: `$scope.messages = [];`

In template I do `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in messages"></div>
```

When I try to do add a new element to the end of array like as:

```
angular.forEach($scope.messages, function (value, key) {
      $scope._lastMsg = key; // Get key of last element of array
});

$scope.messages[++$scope._lastMsg] = obj; // Do increment of next key and add new element obj
```

This way adds element not at end of array, always differently.

Comment: Why not the `push()` function ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to push it at the end with [Array.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```
$scope.messages.push(obj)
```

Comment: I get error: `TypeError: $scope.messages.push is not a function`

Comment: It seems that `$scope.messages` was not initialized as an array before.

Try first: `$scope.messages = []`

Comment: Was initialized in top of controller `$scope.messages = []`

Comment: @Hamed I doubt it. Post your complete controller code in the question.